# Horizontal Scrollable List or Spinner, in smartphones

Tags: interaction-design, android, touch-screen

I have a screen (Android Smartphone) where the user has to make a choice from 2 dropdowns / spinners, second dropdowns' options are dependent on first dropdown's choice.

The number of items in each dropdown can go upto 50.

So i have two options horizontal scrollable list, and spinners. Which is better in my case and how's the selection normally done between these two.

[image: Horizontal Scrollable List]

[image: Spinner]

Comment: Is this a native app or web app?

Comment: There's only one answer to the "Which is better"-part.  Test it with some representative users.

Comment: Its going to be a native app..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say the spinners.

First of all, if you look at the size of both options. In the horizontal list, you can fit five options, if you include the the cropped options. In your mockup of the spinner, you can fit around eight. If you have loads of options, like the 50 you mentioned, more choices is better in my opinion, because you need to do a lot of scrolling to find them.

Secondly, by using the spinners, you can use the devices native controls, which are really fluent. Note that you are able to style the spinner options, so you can still show the little picture within the spinner options.

Comment: Just a point in favor of Horizontal List: you always have both the things in focus and when u need to select both fields pretty fastly, its really handy.

Answer (score 0):

You have another option. To display both lists inline.

So basically you do vertical scrolling, but in both cases the options are visible and available to the user right away.

[image]